# Django-rest-framework: No module named 'rest_framework.reverse_lazy'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have tried reverse of DRF it works

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
reverse("posts-api:article_year_month",args=(2017,1))

'/api/gaurnitai/posts/2017/1'
```

whereas the reverse_lazy is not working:

```
from rest_framework.reverse_lazy import reverse_lazy
reverse_lazy("posts-api:article_year_month",args=(2017,1),request=request)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.reverse_lazy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import should be

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse_lazy
```